# How to completely factor $x^{\varphi(a)} - 1$ when $\gcd(a,x)=1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, factoring, totient-function

In what follows, let $\varphi(a)$ be the [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) of $a \in \mathbb{N}$.

Euler's Theorem (of which Fermat's Little Theorem is a special case) states that

> For any modulus $a$, and any integer $x$ coprime to $a$, one has
>   $$x^{\varphi(a)} \equiv 1 \pmod a.$$

In particular, when $\gcd(a,x)=1$, we have
$$x^{\varphi(a)} - 1 = ab.$$

**Edited**

Here is my question in this post:

> **Is there a closed form (and perhaps, *completely factored expression*) for $b$ in terms of $x$ and $a$?**

**MY OWN THOUGHTS ON THE PROBLEM**

I was thinking that, maybe, something similar to the factorization
$$x^m - 1 = (x - 1)(x^{m-1} + x^{m-2} + \ldots + x + 1)$$
holds for
$$x^{\varphi(a)} - 1 = ab,$$
but I also know that my hunch may be wrong.

Comment: Please unaccept that answer since it is not correct.

Comment: @BillDubuque, thank you for your time and comment.  I have un-accepted KlaasvanAarsen's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your suggested factorization holds.

Furthermore, remember that the expression is zero for any $x$ that is co-prime with $a$.
Therefore for any $k$ that is co-prime with $a$, we have that $(x-k)$ is a factor of $(x^{\varphi(a)}-1)$.

More specifically, if $a$ is a prime, then:
$$x^{\varphi(a)}-1 \equiv x^{a-1}-1 \equiv \prod_{\gcd(k,a)=1} (x-k) \pmod a$$

Comment: I made some minor edits to your MathJAX, @KlaasvanAarsen.  I hope everything is in order.

Comment: Wrong, e.g $\bmod 8\!: (x\!-\!1)(x\!-\!3)(x\!-\!5)(x\!-\!7)\equiv (x\!-\!1)(x\!+\!1)(x\!-\!3)(x\!+\!3)\equiv (x\!-\!1)^2\not\equiv x^4\!-1.\ $ @Jose

Comment: Intriguing congruence, true for $a=10$, but false for $a=15$.

Comment: In response to the various comments, I have un-accepted this answer.

Comment: Typo alert: my comment above should read $\ \ldots\, \equiv (x^{\large\color{#c00}2}-1)^{\large 2}\not\equiv x^{\large 4}-1\ \ \ $

Comment: Rephrased to a weaker version that should be correct.

Comment: I think the original version should still be true if there is an element with order $\varphi(a)$, but I can't prove it yet.

Comment: *Hypothesis:* if $k$ has order $m$, I think we have $x^{\varphi(a)}-1\equiv (x-1)(x-k)\ldots(x-k^{m-1}) (x^{\varphi(a)-m}+\ldots+x^m+1)$.